# XML/PHP: XML doesnt get written properly by my script

Tags: php, xml

I seem to have a small problem, whenever i insert information via a form into my XML file, it adds the information directly IN the previous's entry's child, instead of creating a new child, for the entry, i get something like THIS:

```
<people>
<person>
    <name>Lighty</name>
    <age>17</age>
    <sex>M</sex>
    <comment>iets</comment>
<name>Darky</name><age>22</age><sex>F</sex><comment>things</comment></person>
```

While i need to have something, that would look like THIS:

```
<people>
<person>
    <name>Lighty</name>
    <age>17</age>
    <sex>M</sex>
    <comment>iets</comment>
</person>
    <person>
            <name>Darky</name>
    <age>22</age>
    <sex>F</sex>
    <comment>iets</comment>
</people>
```

i tried using the "$xml->formatOutput = true;" line, but it would just add the child formatOutput with 1 filled in, a complete fail.

Any idea what im doing wrong? here is m PHP Code:

```
<?php

    echo ('Script started');

    //making sure the script only runs when you use a post
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        echo ('-Post accepted');

        //Load XML File into variable
        $xml = simplexml_load_file("phptest3.xml");
        echo ('-XML Loaded');

        //Connect form to Variables 
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $age = $_POST['age'];
        $sex = $_POST['sex'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
  echo ('-Vars connected');

  //Function to strip items that are not needed to prevend XSS/Injections
        function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }
  echo ('-Injections stripped');

        //Create new children in XML file and Connect the from data to the  corresponding XML entries
        $xml->formatOutput = true;
        $xml->people[0];
        $xml->people->addChild('person');
        $xml->person->addChild('name', $name);
        $xml->person->addChild('age', $age);
        $xml->person->addChild('sex', $sex);
        $xml->person->addChild('comment', $comment);
        echo ('-Data inserted');

        //Save current data to XML file...
        $xml->savexml('phptest3.xml');
        echo ('-saved');
    }

    echo ('-Script ended.');

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of [SimpleXMLElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) and [DOMDocument](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

This is how I did it:

```
<pre>
<?php

// Orignal XML - Starting Empty
$xmlStr = "<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<people></people>";

// Load XML
$people = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);

// Debug (Before Add)
echo "<b>Before</b> Add\r\n";
print_r($people);
echo "<hr>\r\n\r\n";

// Add First Person
$newPerson = $people->addChild('person');
$newPerson->addChild('name', 'Lighty');
$newPerson->addChild('age', 17);
$newPerson->addChild('sex', 'M');
$newPerson->addChild('comment', 'iets');

// Debug (After Add)
echo "<b>After</b> Add\r\n";
print_r($people);
echo "<hr>\r\n\r\n";

// Output Modified XML With Formatting
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadXML($people->asXML());
$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo $dom->saveXml();

?>
```

**Browser Outout:**

[image]

**Formatted XML Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<people>
  <person>
    <name>Lighty</name>
    <age>17</age>
    <sex>M</sex>
    <comment>iets</comment>
  </person>
</people>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me after i edited "echo $dom->saveXml()" to "echo $dom->save()".
much appriciated!

Comment: awesome. you're welcome. Another way you could've saved is by: `file_put_contents('phptest3.xml', $dom->saveXml());`